# How to create Edge wear like this image below?

Tags: node-editor, shaders, procedural, shader-nodes

So I a having been trying to do edge wear like this Marine from WARHAMMER created by Pontus Ryman:[image]

I asked him how he produced it, he said he did 100% procedurally in Blender, here is his response:
[image]

Any ideas how to reach  this amazing edge wear detail procedurally? I looked up so many tutorials, but all of them don't get even close to this, specially this part:
[image]

Thanks in advance!

PS: He also did this in EEVEE!

Comment: Is the model all one object, or separate objects? Like is the arm piece separate?

Comment: Separated Objects